# Проблема с Generics

Tags: java, generics

Есть такой метод в классе Num

```java
public Comparable maximumElement(List list){
    return Collections.max(list);
}
```

В другом классе во время обращения к нему таким способом

```java
new Num<>(Collections.emptyList()).maximumElement(Arrays.asList(new Person(), new Person()));
```

я получаю

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Test$1Person cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
```

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы метод `maximumElement()` мог принимать такие параметры.

Comment: Потому что этот метод называется emp**t**yList()

Comment: Спасибо, была опечатка, но проблема оказалась в другом

Comment: >>как расширить возможности метода maximumElement()<< в java нет расширений. Два пути - создать свой хандлер или контейнер, либо править сорсы оригинального класса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что метод `Collections.max(...)` принимает в качестве аргумента коллекцию, элементы которой реализуют интерфейс `Comparable`, что логично - чтобы получить максимальный элемент, нужно уметь сравнивать эти элементы.

Для этого исправьте класс `Person`, добавив реализацию интерфейса `Comparable` и метода с сигнатурой `public int compareTo(Person o)`.

Comment: Спасибо, так действительно работает, но мне нужно расширить количество вариантов параметров которые может принимать метод, или с  Collections.max() так уже не получиться?

Comment: @АндрейОробец а что вы хотите видеть в качестве параметров метода `maximumElement`?

Comment: Задача состоит в том, чтобы метод принимал как можно больше обобщенный тип. Create utility method, which finds maximum element in the given list.

Comment: @АндрейОробец измените сигнатуру метода на `public <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T maximumElement(Collection<T> list)`, тогда сможете принимать любую коллекцию, элементы которой можно сравнить. Впрочем, тогда проще воспользоваться напрямую методом `Collections.max()`, он как раз делает то же самое :)